# adding labels to matrix trees

Tags: tikz-trees

I would like to add labels to the right of the leaves of the following tree. I tried to add the labels to the connecting arrows but they overlap the labels on the nodes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped] 
\matrix (tree) [
  matrix of nodes,
  minimum size=1cm,
  column sep=2cm,
  row sep=.5cm,
]
{
      &   & D \\
      & B &   \\
  A &   & E \\
      & C &   \\
      &   & F \\
};
\draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-2-2) ;
\draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-4-2) ;
\draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-1-3) ;
\draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-3-3) ;
\draw[->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-3-3) ;
\draw[->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-5-3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the picture

[image]

Comment: Do you mean e.g. `\draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-2-2) node[right=5mm] {foo};`

Comment: thanks! I didn't know you can set the distance

Comment: Have  you consider using the graphs syntax?

Comment: I am not familiar with that, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use e.g. `node[right=5mm] {text}` to shift a node right.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped] 
\matrix (tree) [
  matrix of nodes,
  minimum size=1cm,
  column sep=2cm,
  row sep=.5cm,
]
{
      &   & D \\
      &  B &   \\
  A &   & E \\
      & C &   \\
      &   & F \\
};
\draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-2-2) node[right=5mm] {foo};
\draw[->] (tree-3-1) node[right=5mm] {bar} -- (tree-4-2) ;
\draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-1-3) ;
\draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-3-3) ;
\draw[->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-3-3) ;
\draw[->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-5-3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```